# How to treat the whole sentence as one token in Azure Search

Tags: indexing, odata, analyzer, azure-cognitive-search

We are facing a problem of performing exact matching and ignore case-sensitivity by using Azure Search.

For example, we have a field called **Description** and it can be a small sentence or long sentence (For example: **Welcome to Azure Search**). We are trying to treat the whole sentence as one token such that when user search "Welcome to" it won't return the result back because we have to search "Welcome to Azure Search" to do a exactly matching. Another requirement is that we want the capability to search case-insensitive such that searching "welcome TO Azure SEARCH" will return the result.

I have used **Keyword** Analyzer to treat the whole field as a single token but this will prevent search case-insensitive from working.

I am also trying to define custom analyzer with **keyword_v2** tokenizer and **lowercase** token filter. Looks like this will solve my problem however there is a 300 maximum token length limitation. In some of the cases, the Description field will be a long sentence more than 300 characters.

I also thought about duplicating an index field to be lowercase and using **OData syntax $filter=Description eq 'welcome to azure search'**. For example, there will be two fields: **"Description"** and **"DescriptionLowerCase"**, when do the searching, search on **"DescriptionLowerCase"** and when returning result, returning **"Description"**. But this will double the size of index storage.

Is there a better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have pretty much covered all the options available options. At the moment there is no workaround the size limitation as without that the search will suffer performance. Now exactly why would you need exact match on the whole string more than 300 characters is beyond me. Have you tried using quotes around your search?